# What is the filter rule to allow traffic from slave jenkins?

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, aws-security-group

We are having master & slave jenkins in same VPC, but two different public subnets.

we have two separate JSON files(Clouformation template) for master & slave jenkins setup, each.

Below is the security group configuration snippet from master jenkins cloudformation template:

```
"EC2InstanceSecurityGroup":{
            "Type": "AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup",
            "Properties": {
                "GroupDescription": { "Fn::Join": ["", [ { "Ref": "AWS::StackName" }, " ingress security group" ] ] },
                "VpcId": { "Ref": "VpcId" },
                "SecurityGroupIngress": [
                    {
                        "IpProtocol": "tcp",
                        "FromPort": "8080",
                        "ToPort": "8080",
                        "SourceSecurityGroupId": { "Ref": "ElbSecurityGroup"}
                    },
                    {
                        "IpProtocol": "tcp",
                        "FromPort": "22",
                        "ToPort": "22",
                        "CidrIp": "0.0.0.0/0"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
```

---

Master jenkins communicate(two-way) with slave jenkins using 50000 port(JNLP fixed port, by default). For master jenkins send/receive traffic from/to slave jenkins, we need to add one more filter in master jenkins cloudformation template:

```
                {
                    "IpProtocol": "tcp",
                    "FromPort": "50000",
                    "ToPort": "50000",
                    "SourceSecurityGroupId": { "Ref": "SlaveJenkinsSecurityGroup"}
                },
```

---

To allow communication between master & slave,

What is the best approach to mention as source traffic? `SourceSecurityGroupId` or `CidrIp`

Answer (score 1):

The best way is SourceSecurityGroupId, as you can reference it in the same stack or export it to consume by master/slave stack dynamically. This will also useful to replicate the same stack in different environments or accounts.

However, the best practice is to create a common security group and attached to both master and slave (with Ref or ImportValue). Then, you can create an ingress rule in both the primary security groups (master and slave) to allow traffic from the common security group. This way you can also manage the common SG rules through a single SG such as SSH, HTTP/HTTPS rather than putting in both the primary SGs.

Comment: So, do I need to create separate stack just to create SecurityGroupId? and consumed by master stack & slave stack

Comment: Not required. You can create in the same stack either master or slave, depends on which one you are going to create first (suppose master stack), and create an output for that security group which can be consumed by slave stack.

Comment: But the filter rule not the same, for master and slave

Comment: Then you can create a separate stack for all the security groups and export it, and you can refer all your rules within that stacks with a clean approach.